# jQuery fadeOut() only if mouse leaves the shown element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code:

```
var HoverMenuOptions = {
    show: function() {
        $("#UserHoverMenu").css({"display": "block"});
    },

    hide: function() {
        $("#UserHoverMenu").delay(2000).fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).css({"display": "none"});
        });
    }
};
```

I want the div #UserHoverMenu to fadeOut if mouse leaves either the link triggering show() or #UserHoverMenu.

I have tried with:

```
   $('#UserProfileName a').click(function() {

        HoverMenuOptions.show();

    });

   $('#UserProfileName a, #UserHoverMenu').mouseleave(function() {

    HoverMenuOptions.hide();

   });
```

But hide is still triggered if mouse leaves `#UserProfileName a` and then into another div called #UserHoverMenu... How can I break the triggered fadeOut() when I enter #UserHoverMenu with the cursor?

Comment: I just know @Neal is coming to answer this question w/ an awesome fiddle and a kitten.

Comment: @pixelbobby haha :-P very goood

Comment: Well... technically you are making a mistake by having multiple `#UserProfileName`'s.  Id's should be unique, friend.

Comment: Well, the box is unique too, so I can still give that an id ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#UserHoverMenu').mouseenter(function(e){
  $(this).stop(true,true).css({"display": "block"});
});
```

Comment: Hackish... Ugh... Maybe necessary, but I doubt it.

Comment: rather than directly setting the css, he's better off calling HoverMenuOptions.show();